# Accepting a self signed certificate in Java

Tags: jakarta-ee, ssl, ssl-certificate, jboss7.x

I am trying to use Self signed certificate with JBoss and trying to trust in code. But I am getting javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException:. Here are the things I tried,

### Created a keystore

[image: Created a keystore]

### Created a Trust Store

[image]

### Configured SSL in JBoss AS 7.1.1

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
  <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
    <ssl password="password" certificate-key-file="C:\work\certs\ks" protocol="TLSv1" verify-client="false" certificate-file="C:\work\certs\ks"/>
  </connector>
  <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
    <alias name="localhost"/>
    <alias name="example.com"/>
  </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

Started the JBoss. Now I am able to access the site in chrome, by clicking 'Proceed Anyway' button.
[image]

But when I tried access from code, I am getting exception.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:352)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:397)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at com.test.utility.TestHttps.main(TestHttps.java:61)
```

Here is my code,

```
public class TestHttps {

  private static TrustManager[] getTrustManagers() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

    String trustStorePassword = "password";

    String alg = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmFact = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(alg);

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\work\\certs\\trust");
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ks.load(fis, trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
    fis.close();

    tmFact.init(ks);

    TrustManager[] tms = tmFact.getTrustManagers();
    return tms;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(null, getTrustManagers(), null);

    SSLSocketFactory ssf = new SSLSocketFactory(context);

    HttpClient base = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ClientConnectionManager ccm = base.getConnectionManager();
    SchemeRegistry registry = ccm.getSchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", 8443, ssf));

    try {

      DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, base.getParams());
      HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("https://localhost:8443/cafe/");

      HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

      if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
      }

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          (response.getEntity().getContent())));
      String output;
      while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
      }
      httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem by setting the system property

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "SSL,handshake,trustmanager");
```

It seems the problem is with Jboss SSL configuration,

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
  <ssl password="password" certificate-key-file="C:\work\certs\ks" protocol="TLSv1" verify-client="false" certificate-file="C:\work\certs\ks"/>
</connector>
```

removed protocol="TLSv1". And imported the certificate to JRE keystore as

1. accessed the site from browser
2. exported the certificate
3. imported to JRE keystore as

keytool -import -alias localhost -file C:\ssl\test.cer -keystore %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts"

After that the following code works like a charm.

```
String path = "https://localhost:8443/cafe/";

URL url = new URL(path);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String output;
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(output);
}
br.close();
```